# Is there a way to disable accidental link?

Tags: vuepress

Whenever I type in VuePress something that looks like a link, it is displayed on the page as a link. An example is "start.sh". It's just a name of a script that I'm mentioning on my page. VuePress turns it into a link, which is clickable and takes users to some domain, which I do not know.

Is there some way to disable such a link and make it a normal text?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found some simple solution. It is to wrap the accidental link in a `span`:

```html
<span>start.sh</span>
```

This way, the content is no longer a link.